# Outputting .txt to excel using interop

Tags: c#, excel, io

I have a file that I would like to be read into an excel spreadsheet using interop. I'm having trouble reading in the file to my current excel program and cannot get the input file to output at the starting row and column I want. My input file is a bunch of strings that look like this,

HEDGE POSITION     HEDGE      HEDGE      SOUTHERN BAY OPERATING...

I have code that manually creates headers and you can hard code data in there but I want to be able to read in the file and output to an excel spreadsheet starting at [6,1]. Here is my code so far,

```
    public CreateExcelDoc()
    {
        createDoc();
    }
    public void createDoc()
    {
        try
        {
            app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
            worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Error");
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    public void createHeaders(int row, int col, string htext, string cell1,
    string cell2 , int mergeColumns, bool font, int size)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, col] = htext;
        workSheet_range = worksheet.get_Range(cell1, cell2);
        workSheet_range.Merge(mergeColumns);

        workSheet_range.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();
        workSheet_range.Font.Bold = font;
        workSheet_range.Font.Size = size;

        if (fcolor.Equals("w"))
        {
            workSheet_range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.White.ToArgb();
        }
        else
        {
            workSheet_range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();
        }



    }

    public void addData(int row, int col, string data,
        string cell1, string cell2, string format)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, col] = data;
        workSheet_range = worksheet.get_Range(cell1, cell2);
        workSheet_range.Borders.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black.ToArgb();
        workSheet_range.NumberFormat = format;

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

I was thinking about a while loop to read the file in but I couldn't get it working correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of excel file are you writing to?

Comment: Depending on what you have to do, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850837.aspx might be a better option than Interop...

Comment: @jle I'm writing to a .xlsx excel file Excel 2010